# Does the blessing on the karpas cover the pineapple eaten as dessert at the Pesach meal?

Tags: blessing, passover-seder-hagada, marror-bitter-herbs

At the Pesach Seder, there is a custom to make a blessing “borei pri hoadomoh” on the karpas and have in mind that this will cover the moror when it is eaten later.

There is a custom to make a blessing over the dessert of the meal. If the blessing on the dessert would be “borei pri hoadomoh” (eg over pineapple), it seems right to assume that the blessing on the karpas would cover that too. Is this issue dealt with anywhere in the sources?

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward application of [berakhos 6:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.6.5?lang=bi), no?

Comment: @Daniel Besides Brochos 6:5 (which isn't that easy to apply AFAIK) there's also the issue of the entire haggada being a hefsek/gap. Only some opinions allow karpas to exempt marror, whilst others hold we rely on maror being part of the meal (hence the whole "don't eat a kezayis" thing)